# Given an ISO 8601 week number, get date of first day of that week in LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet

Tags: date, libreoffice, iso, libreoffice-calc, week-number

LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet offers a function [`ISOWEEKNUM`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/ISOWEEKNUM) to return the standard [ISO 8601 week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) of the specified date.

I want the opposite.

➠ Given a standard week number, give me the date of the first day of that week (the Monday date).

Passing integers is acceptable. Also nice if able to pass a string in standard format.

Like this:

```
DATE_OF_ISOWEEKNUM( 2017 , 42 ) ➝ date of Monday of week 42 in week-based year 2017
DATE_OF_ISOWEEKNUM( "2017-W42" ) ➝ date of Monday of week 42 in week-based year 2017
```

Ideally, I would be able to pass a number 1-7 for Monday-Sunday to specify the day-of-week for which I want a date. Something like this:

```
DATE_OF_ISOWEEKNUM( 2017 , 42 , 1 ) ➝ date of Monday of week 42 in week-based year 2017
DATE_OF_ISOWEEKNUM( "2017-W42-1" ) ➝ date of Monday of week 42 in week-based year 2017

DATE_OF_ISOWEEKNUM( 2017 , 42 , 7 ) ➝ as above, but Sunday
DATE_OF_ISOWEEKNUM( "2017-W42-7" ) ➝ as above, but Sunday
```

Comment: User `keme` gives a set of formulas to do this at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=14602.  Are you looking for a single function?  If so, `DATE_OF_ISOWEEKNUM` could be implemented with a macro.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

[image]

Formula:

```
=DATE(B$1,1,$A4*7)+(2-WEEKDAY(DATE(B$1,1,$A4*7)))-7*(ISOWEEKNUM(DATE(B$1,1,1))=1)
```

- Calculate the date of day (weeknumber * 7) in the year.
- Correct the day to be weekday Monday.
- Correct to 7 days before, if the first day of the year is in the
  first ISO weeknumber.